# Large data in a cv::Mat or a CvMat*

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

Is **CV_64F largest** dimension/size of a single unit of data that can be stored in a Matrix (**cv::Mat** or CvMat*) using **OpenCV**? Is there anything larger than that?

I want to store large sized data like a **long double** in a cv::Mat. Is there any way I can do it without using arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you can do this *sort of*. You can use the [Mat_](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=mat_#Mat_) template class. Below is a short example I wrote:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>    
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Mat_<long double> testing(Size(5, 5));

    // initialize matrix to ones
    for(int i = 0; i < testing.rows; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < testing.cols; j++)
        {
            testing.at<long double>(i, j) = 1;
        }
    }

    cout << "Element size in bytes is " << testing.elemSize() << "." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Now for the caveat... If you try to use many of the helper methods, `ones`, `zeros`, `operator<<`, and others), you will likely see this error:

```
OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats () in scalarToRawData
```

Hopefully that will be enough that you can use it for some things, but it won't be as clean as usual.

Comment: That was helpful. Why is it that only few primitive types are allowed? Has it got something to do with memory?